# "undo" numpy.delete, numpy.insert?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy array and I want to delete a small number of entries. After that, I'd like to insert the previous indices where they belong. [numpy.insert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) doesn't do the trick:

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.random.rand(7)
idx = [5, 0]

# delete some indices
b = numpy.delete(a, idx)

# magic
b /= 1.0

# insert back?
c = numpy.insert(b, idx, a[idx])

# nope :(
assert numpy.all(numpy.abs(a - c) < 1.0e-10)
```

Any hints? (Simple answers preferred.)

Perhaps there's a better solution than using delete in the first place, e.g., via slicing or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way with `array-assignment` -

```py
out = np.empty(len(b) + len(idx), dtype=b.dtype)
out[idx] = vals
out[np.isin(np.arange(len(out)), idx, invert=True)] = b
```

Another way involves some sorting -

```py
sidx = idx.argsort()
out = np.insert(b, idx[sidx] - np.arange(len(idx)), vals[sidx])
```

Note that the solutions assume the inputs to be arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is just masking with integer indices:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(7)
c = a.copy()
idx = 5, 0

# get the complement of idx
not_idx = np.fromiter((i for i in range(a.size) if i not in idx), dtype=int)
# ...or (mind the final comma: you need a `tuple` of `tuple`s):
not_idx = tuple(i for i in range(a.size) if i not in idx),

# magic
a[not_idx] /= 1.0

# yes!
assert np.all(np.abs(a - c) < 1.0e-10)
# perhaps you would prefer: `np.all(np.isclose(a, c))`?
```

---

A more efficient approach may be to do the "magic" to everything, and then copy the stuff that you wanted unmodified back to the result, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(7)
c = a.copy()
idx = 5, 0

# magic
a /= 1.0

# copy stuff back
a[idx,] = c[idx,]

# yes!
assert np.all(np.abs(a - c) < 1.0e-10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that first realigns the non-deleted bits and then fills in the deleted ones. Admittedly, not too dissimilar to @Divakar's 1st method but as far as I can tell a bit faster:

[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder, MultiArgument

B = BenchmarkBuilder()

@B.add_function()
def pp(b,idx,aidx):
    N,n = b.size,idx.size
    B = np.empty(N+n,b.dtype)
    m = np.ones(N+n,bool)
    m[idx] = False
    B[m] = b
    B[idx] = aidx
    return B

@B.add_function()
def div1(b,idx,vals):
    out = np.empty(len(b)+len(idx),dtype=b.dtype)
    out[idx] = vals
    out[np.isin(np.arange(len(out)),idx, invert=True)] = b
    return out

@B.add_function()
def div2(b,idx,vals):
    sidx = idx.argsort()
    return np.insert(b, idx[sidx]-np.arange(len(idx)), vals[sidx])

@B.add_arguments('array size')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(1,13):
        sz = int(2**exp)
        a = np.random.randint(0,100,sz*sz)
        idx = np.random.choice(sz*sz,sz,replace=False)
        b = np.delete(a,idx)
        yield sz*sz,MultiArgument([b,idx,a[idx]])

r = B.run()
r.plot(relative_to=pp)

import pylab
import pathlib
pylab.savefig(pathlib.Path(__file__).stem + '.png')
```

Comment: Yeah OP said `Simple answers preferred.`. So, I was going more for terseness.